# Code is clean but when running it will not display

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub GenerateAndSearch(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click, btnSearch.Click
    Static intDataArray(-1) As Integer
    Dim btnButtonClicked As Button = sender

    Select Case btnButtonClicked.Tag
        Case "Generate Array"
            Call GenerateSortedArray(intDataArray)

            Me.lstListArrayElements.Items.Clear()
            Call DisplayData(intDataArray, Me.lstListArrayElements, "Sorted array:")

        Case "Search Array"
            Dim intNumToFind As Integer = Val(Me.txtNumToFind.Text)
            Dim intNumFoundIndex As Integer

            intNumFoundIndex = BinarySearch(intDataArray, intNumToFind)
            If intNumFoundIndex = -1 Then
                Me.lblFoundMessage.Text = "Number not found."
            Else
                Me.lblFoundMessage.Text = "Number found at index" & intNumFoundIndex
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Sub GenerateSortedArray(ByRef intArray() As Integer)
    Const intNUMELEMENTS As Integer = 50
    Const intMAXNUMBER As Integer = 100
    ReDim intArray(intNumElements - 1)

    Randomize()
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    For intIndex = 0 To intArray.Length - 1
        intArray(intIndex) = Int(intMAXNUMBER * Rnd()) + 1
    Next intIndex
    Call InsertionSort(intArray)
End Sub

Sub InsertionSort(ByRef intArray() As Integer)
    Dim intIndex, intPreviousIndex, intTempItem As Integer

    For intIndex = 1 To intArray.Length - 1
        intTempItem = intArray(intIndex)
        intPreviousIndex = intIndex - 1

        Do While intPreviousIndex > 0 And
            intArray(intPreviousIndex) > intTempItem
            intArray(intPreviousIndex + 1) = intArray(intPreviousIndex)
            intPreviousIndex = intPreviousIndex - 1
        Loop

        If intArray(intPreviousIndex) > intTempItem Then
            intArray(intPreviousIndex + 1) = intArray(intPreviousIndex)
            intArray(intPreviousIndex) = intTempItem
        Else
            intArray(intPreviousIndex + 1) = intTempItem
        End If
    Next intIndex
End Sub
Sub DisplayData(ByRef intArray() As Integer, ByRef lstList As ListBox, ByVal strTitle As String)
    lstList.Items.Add(strTitle)
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    For intIndex = 0 To intArray.Length - 1
        lstList.Items.Add(intIndex & vbTab & intArray(intIndex))
    Next intIndex
End Sub

Function BinarySearch(ByRef intArray() As Integer, ByVal intNumToFind As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intHighIndex As Integer = intArray.Length - 1
    Dim intMidIndex As Integer
    Dim intLowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim blnFound As Boolean = False

    Do While (Not blnFound) And (intLowIndex <= intHighIndex)
        intMidIndex = (intMidIndex + intLowIndex) / 2
        If intArray(intMidIndex) = intNumToFind Then
            blnFound = True
        ElseIf intArray(intMidIndex) > intNumToFind Then
            intHighIndex = intMidIndex - 1
        Else
            intLowIndex = intMidIndex + 1
        End If
    Loop
    If blnFound Then
        Return intMidIndex
    Else
        Return -1
    End If
End Function
Private Sub NewData_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtNumtoFind.TextChanged, btnGenerate.Click
    Me.lblFoundMessage.text = Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

My problem is I cannot get my code to display a list of arrays to find. I cant see where im going wrong any ideas? Also my sort button is not working but that may be due to the fact nothing shows up when i click button `btnGenerate`.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes @DonA The Program will run just will not display.

Comment: Is `Form1` the start-up form or no?

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you mean by that @KarlAnderson but if im correct i believe your asking if form1 starts right away and the answer is yes I only have two tabs Form1.vb and Form1.vb[Design].

Comment: So the values you see while debugging are what you would expect? I mean stepping thru the code not just hitting the Debug arrow.

Comment: Yes i stepped into no problems there @DonA

Comment: You should test/debug your sort function indipendently. By quickly looking at it, I don't think it does what you think it should do. Debugging mean testing each part one by one. Step through the code, see if your array is correctly populated/sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem appears to be in your BinarySearch function.  The reason you weren't getting any display is the BinarySearch function had an infinite loop.  Here's some corrected code with explanations and is tested and working:

```
Function BinarySearch(ByRef intArray() As Integer, ByVal intNumToFind As Integer) As Integer
    Dim intHighIndex As Integer = intArray.Length - 1
    Dim intMidIndex As Integer
    Dim intLowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim blnFound As Boolean = False

    Do While (Not blnFound) And (intLowIndex <= intHighIndex)
        'This should add high and low then divide by 2 not mid and low
        'Also you should use the integer division sign to return an integer result
        intMidIndex = (intHighIndex + intLowIndex) \ 2
        If intArray(intMidIndex) = intNumToFind Then
            blnFound = True
            'mid should become the new limit without any inc/decrement
        ElseIf intArray(intMidIndex) > intNumToFind Then
            intHighIndex = intMidIndex
        Else
            intLowIndex = intMidIndex
        End If
    Loop
    If blnFound Then
        Return intMidIndex
    Else
        Return -1
    End If
End Function
```

A couple of other corrections that should be made:

`Select Case btnButtonClicked.Tag` should be `Select Case btnButtonClicked.Tag.ToString()`

`intArray(intIndex) = Int(intMAXNUMBER * Rnd()) + 1` should be `intArray(intIndex) = CInt(intMAXNUMBER * Rnd()) + 1`

One other thought, you might want to put a check in the generate routine to only generate unique numbers.  Binary search will only find one element but not any of the others if there are more.

Answer (score 0):

The NewData_TextChanged method erases your search results:

```
Me.lblFoundMessage.text = Nothing
```

Remove that line of code and the results should be displayed.

Comment: I pretty much copied your code and it displays for me.  Are you sure that you set your Button's Tag Property in the designer (without fat fingering a double space or something)?  Case sensitivity would apply here.

Comment: How did youre designer look?? @NoAlis